# On the proof of Lemma 3.17 in Harris - Algebraic Geometry, A First Course

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question is motivated by the proof of **Lemma 3.17 in Algebraic Geometry, First Course by Joe Harris**.

Let $Y$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$ and consider the projection $\pi : Y 
\times \mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow Y$ onto the first factor. Let $U$ be a locally closed subset of $Y \times \mathbb{P}^1$, hence $U = \bar{U} \cap V$, where $\bar{U}$ is the closure of $U$ and $V$ some open subset of $Y \times \mathbb{P}^1$. Suppose that $\pi(U)$ is dense in $Y$ and that 
 $\bar{U} \subsetneq Y \times \mathbb{P}^1$. Let $T$ be the complement of $V$ in $Y \times \mathbb{P}^1$.

**Objective:** Show that $\pi(X \cap T) \neq Y$.

Harris gives the following argument:

> After restricting to an open set of $Y$, the ideals of $X, T$ are generated by polynomials of the form $F=a_0 Z^n + a_1 Z^{n-1}W+\cdots+a_n W^n$. What is more, not every pair of polynomials $F \in I(X), G \in I(T)$ can have a common factor: if for example every $G \in I(T)$ had a common factor $H$ with a given $F \in I(X)$, it would follow that $H$ is non-zero on $U$ and so $F/H \in I(X)$. But if $F,G$ have no common factor, the image of $\pi(X \cap T)$ will be contained in the proper subvariety of $Y$ defined by the resultant $R(F,G)$.

**Question**: I do not understand the argument by which he concludes that not every pair $F,G$ have a common factor. Why is he taking $H$ to be the **same** common factor of $F$ with every $G \in I(T)$?

For the convenience of the community:
[image]